# Can I use class attributes as function argument in python?

Tags: python, class, attributes

I wanna do something like

```
class myclass(object):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
        self.arg3 = arg3

    def printattribute(self, arg):
        print(self.arg)

a = myclass(1,2,3)
a.printattribute(arg2)
```

and have it printing the value of `a.arg2`, but I keep getting `a do not have arg attribute`. How do I make python understand and change `arg` after the dot notation, so that things like this

```
def createlist(self, flag):
    myset = set()
    if flag == 'size':
        for myfile in self.group:
            myset.add(myfile.size)
    if flag == 'head':
        for myfile in self.group:
            myset.add(myfile.head)
    if flag == 'tail':
        for myfile in self.group:
            myset.add(myfile.tail)
    if flag == 'hash':
        for myfile in self.group:
            myset.add(myfile.hash)
    return sorted(myset)
```

turns into

```
def createlist(self, flag):
    myset = set()
    for myfile in self.group:
        myset.add(myfile.flag)
    return sorted(myset)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i think what you are looking for is `getattr`

```
 def printattribute(self, arg):
        print(getattr(self,arg))
```

to call it you will use something like:

```
a.printattribute('arg2')
```

your final function will probably look like this:

```
def createlist(self, flag):
    myset = set()
    for myfile in self.group:
        myset.add(getattr(myfile, flag))
    return sorted(myset)
```